# InstallShield 2009 Pre install

Tags: installshield

Is there any option to copy some of the files (pre installation) to the system before onFirstUIBefore() method. These files are also part of installer.
I am using install shield 2009 and project type is installer script.

EDIT:
Some more info. we need to run one utility which is part of setup.exe package. It should be run first in the OnFirstUIMethod() before showing up other dialogs to the user. There are around 5 dialogs in OnFirstUIMethod() method. The utility has some complex code and it's functionality can't be done with installer scripts (that's why this utility). My requirement is this utility should be part of installer package. Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add filed to the Support Files/Billboards section of the project, you can reference them in your project and specifically in OnBegin.

For example, if you have a file called foo.exe that you needed to execute, you could add it to the project as a Support File and the reference it using the SUPPORTDIR keyword. It would look something like this:

```
LaunchAppAndWait(SUPPORTDIR ^ foo.exe);
```

Answer (score 1):

The OnBegin event is the first place you can do custom things in an InstallScript project, like copy files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, using onBegin() method we can copy files, read registry etc.. But, how can I handle copying the files which are in setup.exe itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  When you package the installer the files needed by setup.exe are included in the package, then unpacked & used at runtime.  Why do *you* want to copy them to the local filesystem?  I'm currently converting our InstallScript setups to IS 2009 from IS 11.5 and have not had to do what you're talking about.